# UitableView in UitableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm a newbie in iOS.

I have a `UITableView` and a `DetailViewController`. When I click some elements (like name of user) in a `UITableView` it will transfer to the `DetailViewController`. Then I could code for that 2 `ViewController`s.

But now I want to be able to click elemens in the `DetailViewController` so that it will move to another `DetailViewConTroller` and so on. Just like in the Facebook app where you click a username and it moves to that user's timeline. And in that user's timeline you can click on another username etc.

So do I have to write code for 3 (4, 5, 6...) `ViewControllers` or is there a reliable way I can write code for 2 `ViewController`s only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to code two view controllers. From your first `DetailViewController`, you create and push a new `DetailViewController`. The one you pushed will have the exact same code, so you can push another `DetailViewController`.

If you have no top level view controller which is different from those DetailViewControllers, then you only need to code *one* type of view controller.

Note that this way of doing things needs to have your DetailViewControllers contained in a `UINavigationController`, which handles the pushing of new view controllers.

Comment: @Nevan king So your way is the best solution to fix my problem? so I can accept your answer. If you have any sample project or links about your way please give me. I will learn from it. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: @H2CO3 is it just 1 view :D?

Comment: @jackiviet Yes, only one, and recursion (or whatever).

Comment: @H2CO3 It depends. It wasn't really clear if the table view was actually a table view controller which led to a detail view controller. In that case, it's 2 view controllers.

Comment: @jackiviet There's a lot of sample code in the documentation for Xcode. I'd suggest having a look at "SimpleDrillDown" to learn the basics of navigation controllers and pushing view controllers.

Comment: @H2CO3 I will google it if I dont know I wil ask you later. Thank you in advanced.